# Prettier does not format HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier has just stopped working and is not formatting HTML in my VSCode.
In the output I get:
["ERROR" - 5:00:45 PM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 5:00:45 PM] Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags (62:90)

Does anyone know what I can do to get working again?
Ive checked my various settings and not been able to see anything wrong.

Comment: I suspect that you have an error somewhere in your code that is causing this. The error says that you may have closed a `<p>` tag twice. Have a read through your code and see if you can find it. If not, add your code to the question.

Comment: Hi Jonah!! I've opened the HTML in the browser and it all looks fine there. I've tried to open other workspaces (react, javascript, css etc) but my code is not being formatted at all in VSCode.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but could you maybe send me the code somehow? Either a pastebin or adding it to your question. I may be able to try and find the error. I'd be reasonably confident that it's an error in the code, but not all errors in code make a change in the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally solved it.
I have in settings the default formatter as `esbenp.prettier-vscode`, then what I have done is in the html file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> preferences: configure language specific settings... then you search html and then you should have open the settings.json. in there I just pasted this

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    }
}
```

and I don't know why but works